# Memoizing finite horizon dynamic programming

Tags: julia, dynamic-programming, memoization

I will try asking [my questions](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/memoizing-finite-horizon-dynamic-programming/19731) here:

So I am trying to program a simple finite horizon dynamic programming problem.

I'm trying to use memoization to speed-up computation time.

```
using Optim

V2dict = Dict()

function V2(t, K)
    if t >= T
        return 0.0
    else
        if haskey(V2dict, (t, K))
            return V2dict[t, K]
        else
            opt = optimize(K′ -> -(log(K - K′) + β * V2(t+1, K′)), eps(), K, iterations = 100_000)
            V2dict[t, K] = Optim.minimum(opt)
            return V2dict[t, K]
        end
    end
end

T = 6
β = 0.95

@time V2(1, 100)
#-6.333197046721626
# 32.262246 seconds (1.36 G allocations: 21.515 GiB, 14.51% gc time)
```

I have two questions:

Is that how memoization is supposed to be implemented?

Why is `V2dict` saving many keys for each `t`? I am only trying to save the optimal values for `V2`.

```
V2dict
Dict{Any,Any} with 1799 entries:
  (4, 3.32187e-5)  => -24.3578
  (5, 5.22198e-15) => 32.9762
  (5, 4.50844e-16) => 36.4949
  (4, 8.69678e-5)  => -25.3202
  (5, 2.6052e-12)  => 26.6737
  (5, 2.19599e-9)  => 19.9366
  (5, 7.22726e-16) => 35.7118
  (5, 3.94054e-8)  => 17.0494
  (5, 0.118624)    => 2.1318
  (4, 1.3312e-14)  => -2.68559
  (4, 0.000596086) => -27.245
  (3, 4.50844e-16) => 35.5843
  (5, 6.72888e-16) => 35.8166
  (5, 0.0453104)   => 3.09422
  ⋮                => ⋮
```

Comment: Side note: `get!(f::Function, collection, key)` can make your code more elegant, removing the `if haskey ...`.

Comment: You mean to write `get!(V2(t, K), V2dict, (t, K))`? is there any performance penalty?

Comment: No, like [that](https://pastebin.com/G2Fhs8Qt). The first argument has to be a function, not a call. As for the performance: I don't know, but I'd guess not really.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a reasonable implementation of memoization for the `V2` function.

The output of `V2` depends not on just the first parameter `t` but also on the second parameter `K`. So to memoize the output of `V2`, the dictionary key has to include both `t` and `K`, which it does. But that means you're going to get multiple keys with the same `t` value, because `t` is not the whole key; the key is `(t, K)`.

It may be that you're not trying to memoize the `V2` function but rather just construct a dictionary of `t` values to the lowest value of `V2` found for that `t` (across all values of `K`). If that's the case then you can just have the dictionary key be `t` by itself and replace the existing value whenever you discover a "better" one.